# Idempotent table and index creation with value insertion in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have some SQL Server schema changes that I'm trying to convert to MySQL. I know about `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in MySQL. I don't think I can use that here.

What I want to do is create a table in MySQL, with an index, and then insert some values all as part of the "if not exists" predicate. This was what I came up with, though it doesn't seem to be working:

```
SET @actionRowCount = 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @actionRowCount
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'Action'
LIMIT 1;

IF @actionRowCount = 0 THEN
    CREATE TABLE Action
    (
        ActionNbr INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        Description NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_Action PRIMARY KEY(ActionNbr)
    );

    CREATE INDEX IX_Action_Description
    ON Action(Description);

    INSERT INTO Action
        (Description)
    VALUES
        ('Activate'),
        ('Deactivate'),
        ('Specified');
END IF
```

I can run it once, and it'll create the table, index, and values. If I run it a second time, I get an error: `Table Action already exists`. I would have thought that it wouldn't run at all if the table already exists.

I use this pattern a lot when bootstrapping a schema. How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: One option is to use a stored procedure, see [14.1.16 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples of options:

Option 1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Action` (
    `ActionNbr` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `IX_Action_Description` (`Description`)
) SELECT 'Activate' `Description`
  UNION
  SELECT 'Deactivate'
  UNION
  SELECT 'Specified';
```

Option 2:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_create_table_Action`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_create_table_Action`()
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
          FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` `ist`
          WHERE `ist`.`table_schema` = DATABASE() AND
                `ist`.`table_name` = 'Action') THEN

        CREATE TABLE `Action` (
            `ActionNbr` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `Description` NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT `PK_Action` PRIMARY KEY (`ActionNbr`)
        );

        CREATE INDEX `IX_Action_Description`
        ON `Action` (`Description`);

        INSERT INTO `Action`
            (`Description`)
        VALUES
            ('Activate'),
            ('Deactivate'),
            ('Specified');
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL `sp_create_table_Action`;
```

Answer (score 2):

In mysql [compound statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html) can only be used within stored programs, which includes the `if` statement as well.

Therefore, one solution is to include your code within a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html).

The other solution is to use the `create table if not exists ...` with the separate index creation included within the table definition and using `insert ignore` or `insert ... select ...` to avoidd inserting duplicate values.